# What is the difference between the pose of a robot and the configuration of a robot?

Tags: mobile-robot, wheeled-robot, manipulator

Do "configuration" and "pose" means the same thing? If not what is the difference?

Comment: This might be a good question, but unfortunately it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to understand, what you've researched so far, what you found & what you expected to find. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do "configuration" and "pose" means the same thing?

No.

---

One of the most clear definitions of '***pose***' that I've heard is in Peter Corke's *[Robotics, Vision and Control](http://petercorke.com/wordpress/rvc/)* (RVC).  It states that:

> "**The position and orientation of a coordinate frame is known as its pose** and is shown graphically as a set of coordinate axes. The relative pose of a frame with respect to a reference coordinate frame is denoted by the symbol ξ".

The following figure is figure 2.2 in RVC:

[image: pose]

The point P can be described by coordinate vectors relative to either frame {A} or {B}. The **pose** of {B} relative to {A} is $ ^{A} ξ _{B} $

---

The '***configuration***' of a robot is a set of scalar parameters that specify the positions of all of the robot's points relative to some fixed coordinate system.  This can be expressed as a vector of positions and orientations, for example:

q = ($x$, $y$, $\theta$)

or

q = (($x$, $y$, $z$, $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$))

The set of all possible configurations is the '*configuration space*', or '*C-space*'.

---

If we consider the two-link planar manipulator with 2 revolute joints (2R-arm), shown here (taken from fig 7.3 in RVC):

[image: 2R arm]

The ***configuration*** can be expressed in terms of just the two joint angles $\theta _{1}$ and $\theta _{2}$, while the ***configuration space*** is the set of all possible combinations of the joint angles $\theta _{1}$ and $\theta _{2}$.

Note that configurations are not necessarily unique. For this robot, there are two possible configurations that result in the same end-effector position, but the end effector will have a different orientation in each case.

---

A worked example using MATLAB can be found in the [Analyzing a 2-joint planar robot arm](https://robotacademy.net.au/lesson/analyzing-a-2-joint-planar-robot-arm/) lesson on Peter's [QUT Robot academy](https://robotacademy.net.au/). This includes a visual description of the 2R-arm shown above.